# Reduce hash with key, value and index as block parameters

Tags: ruby

```
h = { "a" => 1, "b" => 2 }
```

Is there a way to reduce a hash and have the key, value and index as block parameters?

As a starting point I can iterate over a hash getting key, value and index:

```
h.each_with_index { |(k,v), i| puts [k,v,i].inspect }

# => ["a", 1, 0]
# => ["b", 2, 1]
```

However when I add `reduce` I seem to loose the ability to have the key and value as separate values and instead they are provided as a two element array:

```
h.each_with_index.reduce([]) { |memo, (kv,i)| puts [kv,i].inspect }

# => [["a", 1], 0]
# => [["b", 2], 1]
```

This is okay, I can in the block do `kv[0]` and `kv[1]`, but I'd like something like this:

```
h.each_with_index.reduce([]) { |memo, (k,v), i| puts [k,v,i].inspect }
```

I'd like to do this without monkey-patching.

Comment: You are fortunate to have received (so far) three very good answers. I suggest you study @mudasobwa's answer for a deeper understanding of what's going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this?:

```
h.each_with_index.reduce([]) { |memo, ((k,v), i)| puts [k,v,i].inspect }
#=> ["a", 1, 0]
#=> ["b", 2, 1]
#=> nil
```

All you need is scoping: `((k,v), i)`.

Keeping in mind with `reduce`, we always have to return the object at the end of block. Which is kind of an extra overhead unless last operation isn't on the `memo` object which returns the object itself.Otherwise it won't return the desired result.

Same thing can be achieved with `each_with_index` chained with `with_object` like so:

```
h.each_with_index.with_object([]) { |((k,v), i), memo| memo << [k,v,i].inspect }
#=> ["a", 1, 0]
#=> ["b", 2, 1]
#=> []
```

See the array at last line of output? That's our `memo` object, which isn't same as `reduce` that we used above.

Answer (score 3):

[`Enumerable#each_with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) yields two values into the block: the item and its index. When it is invoked for a `Hash`, the item is an array that contains two elements: the key and the associated value.

When you declare the block arguments `|(k,v), i|` you, in fact, deconstruct the first block argument (the item) into its two components: the key and the value. Without a block `h.each_with_index` produces an [`Enumerator`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerator.html) that yields both arguments of the previously used block wrapped into an array.

This array is the second argument of [`Enumerator#reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce).

You can tell this by running:

```
irb> h.each_with_index.reduce([]) { |memo, j| p j }
[["a", 1], 0]
[["b", 2], 1]
```

Now, the answer to your question is easy: just deconstruct `j` and you get:

```
irb> h.each_with_index.reduce([]) { |memo, ((k,v), i)| puts [k,v,i].inspect }
["a", 1, 0]
["b", 2, 1]
```

Of course, you should `memo << [k,v,i]` or put the values in `memo` using other other rules and return `memo` to get your final desired result.

Answer (score 3):

When in doubt what the block arguments are, create an instance of an [`Enumerator`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html) and call [`#next`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) on it:

```
▶ h = {a: 1, b: 2}
#⇒ {:a=>1, :b=>2}
▶ enum = h.each.with_index.with_object([])
#⇒ #<Enumerator: ...>

▶ enum.next
#⇒ [[[:a, 1], 0], []]
```

The returned value consists of:

- array of `key` and `value`, joined into:
- array with an `index`, joined into:
- array with an accumulator (for `reduce` it’d go in front, if `reduce` returned an enumerator when called without a block—credits to @Stefan for nitpicking.)

Hence, the proper parentheses for decomposing it would be:

```
#   ⇓ ⇓     ⇓       ⇓
# [ [ [:a, 1],    0 ],    [] ]
{ | ( (k,  v),  idx ),   memo| ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `reduce` doesn't return an enumerator.

Comment: @Stefan another reason to not use `reduce` with a mutable accumulator :)

Comment: Fair enough ;-)

Comment: Nice tip using `next`.

Comment: Very good answer, especially the concentration on the enumerator. Consider writing `( (k,  v),  idx ),   memo = enum.next` and simply show the values this assigns to the four block variables.